# Multi dot - k1global1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(invt1, k1local, t1)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

The multi dot function can´t multiply 3 matrixes?
On my code I´m getting this error: _multidot_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

```
t1 = np.matrix([[l1, m1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [-m1, l1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0 , 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, l1, m1, 0], [0, 0, 0, -m1, l1, 0], [0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

k1local = np.matrix([[a1, 0, 0, -a1, 0, 0], [0, b1, c1, 0, -b1, c1], [0, c1, d1, 0, -c1, e1], [a1, 0, 0, a1, 0, 0], [0, -b1, -c1, 0, b1, -c1], [0, c1, e1, 0, -c1, d1]])

invt1 = np.linalg.inv(t1)

k1global1 = np.linalg.multi_dot(invt1, k1local, t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`multi_dot` takes a sequence of arrays as its input, not each array individually that should be part of the multiplications. That is why you get that error. You have to change your code to `k1global1 = np.linalg.multi_dot([invt1, k1local, t1])`